# When were st, nd, rd, and th, first used

Tags: abbreviations, contractions, typography, ordinal-numbers, superscripts

When were numeric contractions for ordinals first used, as in *1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup>, 6<sup>th</sup>* instead of *first, second, third, sixth*?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the history of writing in the Latin alphabet, not about English language or usage.

Comment: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th are ***English*** contractions. In French, they are 1er, 2e, 3e — or maybe 1er, 2ème, 3ème. And in German,  ordinals aren't contracted this way. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator).

Comment: @PeterShor I would at some level argue that they are not strictly speaking “contractions” *per se*.  Because if they are, then *7,000* is a “contraction” of *seven thousand* — which I don’t buy for one minute.

Comment: Related: [What do we call the “rd” in “3ʳᵈ” and the “th” in “9ᵗʰ”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192804)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator) in Latin, ordinals were indicated by superscripts on Roman numerals.

> XX<sup>o</sup> *vicensimo*

Not all languages currently do this; for example German and most Eastern European languages do not. Most Romance languages do, along with a number of others, including Dutch and English.

In English, Wikipedia says these started out as superscripts: 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup>, but during the 20<sup>th</sup> century they migrated to the baseline: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th.

So the practice started during the Roman empire, and probably was continuously used since then in the Romance languages.

I don't know when it was adopted in English. [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=veBbAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=1st&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BmLgUpr9PJTNsATIiYDoCg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=1st&f=false) is a pamphlet entitled:

> Mr. *PRYNNE*'s New-Year's-GIFT,
>   to the *Rump-Parliament* &c.
>   The 1ſt of *January*, 1648-9.

So it goes back a long way … I would suspect that you can find these contractions near the beginning of printed matter in English.

Comment: They migrated to the baseline because of the tyranny of the typewriter and the chains of ASCII. :)