# What do we call the “rd” in “3ʳᵈ” and the “th” in “9ᵗʰ”?

Tags: orthography, numbers, suffixes, typography, ordinal-numbers

Our numbers have a specific two-letter combination that tells us how the number sounds.

For example

- 9<sup>th</sup>
- 3<sup>rd</sup>
- 301<sup>st</sup>

What do we call these special sounds?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia): An onomatopoeia  [from the Greek ὀνοματοποιία; ὄνομα for "name" and ποιέω for "I make"]; adjectival form: "onomatopoeic" or "onomatopoetic") is a word that phonetically imitates, resembles or suggests the source of the sound that it describes. Like _oink_, _tick tock_. Not applicable here.

Comment: Just a small remark: According to the English typography, the ordinal indicators are not written in superscript. In French or Spanish you do that, not in English. It's only Microsoft Word that implemented the feature years ago and since then, people think it's correct.

Comment: It's a suffix. The way it's printed varies, but it's the ordinal suffix that distinguishes an ordinal number from the corresponding cardinal number.

Comment: @tohecz Er, says who?! I read those forms in English text long decades before Micosoft Word ever cursed the world with its existence.  Plus you’re wrong about French and Spanish: those ones up there are uniquely English.  You can only have a 3ʳᵈ wife or 3ʳᵈ husband in English alone; in Spanish you’d have a *3ª esposa* or a *3º marido*, whatever suits your fancy. Do not let the tyranny of the typewriter cast out everything we ever knew about typography, which is something else altogether.

Comment: @tohecz — The ordinal indicators in english were originally written in superscript, way before Microsoft Word.

Comment: @tchrist You're second point doesn't disagree with tohecz - he wasn't saying the letters were the same, just the act of superscripting was French/Spanish.

Comment: @tohecz You are correct that *in the US* they were baseline in C.20 , but historically they are superscript in English - it's a style of abbreviation, e.g. 'equation'->'eq^n' (superscript may be underlined too). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator#English

Comment: @OllieFord You are wrong—he is not second point doesn't disagree with tohecz. He's just a guy on the internet.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou Me: "What the hell is he talki-- aaaarggggghh!" Edit period :'(

Comment: I am a pedantic hippo.

Comment: @tchrist A little correction: since, in Spanish, the third husband would be 'tercer marido' (the ordinal is in the shorter form, instead of 'tercero'), hence 3.<sup>er</sup>. While making sure, I learned that the official form includes the dot in the middle. I would say few people use it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's an [*ordinal indicator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator):

> In written languages, an ordinal indicator is a letter, or group of letters, following a numeral denoting that it is an ordinal number, rather than a cardinal number. Historically these letters were "elevated terminals", that is to say the last few letters of the full word denoting the ordinal form of the number displayed as a superscript. The exact letters used vary in different languages.

(source: Wikipedia)

Comment: So far as dates are concerned, am I right in believing that Americans don't use these 'ordinal indicators' very much?

Comment: In my experience we do; today is August 22nd. If I were British or Irish, today would probably be 22 August.

Comment: @WS2 In speech, very nearly always. In writing, much less so. I think what may be going on is that one just assumes that “June 1” is pronounced “June First”, or “4 July” as “the Fourth of July”.  So your perception that they are not so much used in America may be from the lazy or abbreviated or “assumed” written versions not the actual oral ones. So for example if you were born on February 13, you would say aloud that you were born on February Thirteenth — never on February *Thirteen, which doesn’t even sound grammatical for some reason.

Comment: @tchrist But where you do differ from us, both in spoken and written form, is that you omit the definite article. We would say 'on February *the* thirteenth', never 'on February thirteenth'.

Comment: @WS2 Hmm, that sure sounds more like Friday the Thirteenth ’round these parts. But I wonder: do you also say *I saw him on February the first* as well?  If so, then things are weirder than I realized.

Comment: +1 There's more to it and the WP entry cited by you itself covers much ground already.

Comment: When Brits write 22 August, do they pronounce it, "August the 22nd?"

Comment: @RoboKaren, no - as "the 22nd of August".

Comment: @tchrist Either that, or "the first of February".

Answer (score 3):

In the case of *9<sup>th</sup>,* the superscript shown is indeed called the 'ordinal indicator' as Matt Gutting has noted in his answer.

The addition of *-th/ -eth* relates to numbers **4** to **20** (and similarly,) and is a suffix to the **cardinal** number.

However, as in the second and third examples, the *rd* & *st* simply come from the right-end of the word for the **ordinal** number:

*3<sup>rd</sup>: thi **rd***

*301<sup>st</sup>: (three-hundred-) fir **st*** (shouldn't that be 301 ***th*** ?, I'm not going there).

Of course, in general, we call all these superscripts 'ordinal indicators,' and "suffixes," 'ordinal suffixes.' (We can see that there's no suffix as such until we come to **4,** as we have **ordinal names.**)

Comment: I would regard the "nd" in "second" as a suffix on the *number* "3", like the "th" in "20th".  For example, I would suggest that "VIP" [Very Important Person] is made plural by adding a "-s" suffix, even though the resultant phrase [Very Important People] doesn't contain the letter "s" anywhere within it.

Comment: @supercat VIPs: Very Important **Persons** -- where are the people coming from :) Even otherwise, you **can** pluralize an abbreviation by itself, *cf.* RADARs.

Answer (score 1):

First, these abbreviations are not *onomatopoeia*.

In fact, your question is about *writing* rather than *sounds*.

In the written number *2<sup>nd</sup>*, the letters *<sup>nd</sup>* are ***the superscript***.

More generally, these letters form [***the ordinal indicator***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ordinal_indicator) in english.

Comment: The question has been edited. My answer applies to the question as I saw it, with the superscripts.

Answer (score 0):

These are ***ordinal suffixes***.

> *Ordinal formatter: add ordinal suffixes (-st, -nd, -rd, -th) to numbers.* [finzi.psych.upenn.edu](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/scales/html/ordinal_format.html)