# is there limit on the integer allow to use `st`, `nd`, `rd` that ends with 1,2, and 3 accordingly?

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, numbers

I know we use `st`, `nd`, `rd` on numbers before `1`, `2`, and `3` accordingly... But at what point should the number stop using that.

For example, if we have a number extremely large like 100002, should we still do `100002nd`?

Or maybe its up to only two digits?

I read this one btw, [When were st, nd, rd, and th, first used](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147364/when-were-st-nd-rd-and-th-first-used)

But It did not give the answer I want.

Thanks all!

Comment: After 11, 12, 13, or numbers ending in these digits, you must use th because they are pronounced eleventh, twelfth, thirteenth.

Comment: Yes and Ezeewei, there is no limit… Write out Pi to a million places and the millionth is still the millionth, etc, ad nauseam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the pronunciation.  If you say "This is the one million and second time you told me" then you would write "1000002nd".  Do not write "1000002th" unless you pronounce it "one million and twoth" (which is extremely nonstandard).

Comment: Yes I would definitely say "the one hundred and second, or one hundred and third time" - written "102nd, 103rd time".

Comment: 101st Airborne . . .